# Magento Disabled Product shows 500 internal server error

Tags: magento, product

I am facing a weird issue out here.

For a product, if I disable it from Admin end, and run product URL in browser, it shows me 500 internal server error.

**For eg: http://domain.com/product.html**

Now If I add a random param to the URL and again run it, it gives me a 404 error page as expected.

**Eg: http://domain.com/product1.html**

This thing is happening whenever I disable my product from Live site while my staging site is working well even if I disable any product.

What could be the issue for server error if my product is disabled from admin ?

I checked .htaccess and it has no issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable compilation and see if the error persists. This is a bug, described here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/310970/

The suggested solution is:
in lib/Varien/Autoload.php :: registerScope, just change include to include_once :

```
 static public function registerScope($code)
  {
    self::$_scope = $code;
    if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
      // Change to include_once to prevent including multiple times !!!
      //@include COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .    self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
      @include_once COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Compilation issues are most likely caused by some event listeners, which invoke classes already included in area-specific compiled files (e.g. `_default.php`, `_checkout.php`, etc).

Since the `Varien_Autoload` class uses the shut-up `@` operator for `include`, it fails silently (no error messages are logged) because a class already defined via `Varien_Autoload` is being re-defined in any of such area-specific compiled files (or vice-versa).

The proper solution to this problem would be to identify the correct classes to group in compiled files, for each area, inclusive of their hierarchical dependencies, by amending (or overloading) the compiler's config file in originally located in `app/code/core/Mage/Compiler/etc/compilation.xml`.

To identify such a group, you can temporarily remove the `@` before `include` in `Varien_Autoload`, and run Magento in developer mode (see comments in `index.php`): this way, on each page load, the conflicting classes will be reported as an error by the failing `include`. Move the reported classes, along with their hierarchical parents, to the `<default>` section of the `complilation.xml` file, making sure there are no duplicates in any of the sections, recompiling and testing until no errors are reported, and then put the `@` back in place, to restore the original Magento core class file.

Another approach could be to list the event handlers (specially the "early" ones as the `_predispatch` event family) implemented by the 3rd party modules installed, and move the classes used in those event handlers (and their hierarchical parents) to the `<default>` section in `compilation.xml` file.

The solution proposed by **@Socrates** may work, but it has several disadvantages:

- a core class file has to be modified (which may affect patches, upgrades etc);
- `include_once` is less efficient and more memory-consumptive if compared to simple `include`;
- optimisation offered by Magento compilation mechanism could be degraded.